# Commas between between embedded ruby expression tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, list, embedded-ruby

My rails app includes a form for users to setup a profile. A section of the form allows the users to select from a long list the services and they may choose up to 5 different services.

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :services_1 %>
    <%= f.select :services_1, ['Service 1', 'Service 2', 'Service 3', 'Service 4', 'Service 5', 'Service 6', 'Service 7', 'Service 8', 'Service 9', 'Service 9', ], {}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :services_2 %>
    <%= f.select :services_2, ['Service 1', 'Service 2', 'Service 3', 'Service 4', 'Service 5', 'Service 6', 'Service 7', 'Service 8', 'Service 9', 'Service 9', ], {}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :services_3 %>
    <%= f.select :services_3, ['Service 1', 'Service 2', 'Service 3', 'Service 4', 'Service 5', 'Service 6', 'Service 7', 'Service 8', 'Service 9', 'Service 9', ], {}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :services_4 %>
    <%= f.select :services_4, ['Service 1', 'Service 2', 'Service 3', 'Service 4', 'Service 5', 'Service 6', 'Service 7', 'Service 8', 'Service 9', 'Service 9', ], {}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
      
      <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :services_5 %>
    <%= f.select :services_5, ['Service 1', 'Service 2', 'Service 3', 'Service 4', 'Service 5', 'Service 6', 'Service 7', 'Service 8', 'Service 9', 'Service 9', ], {}, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
```

I want to list these on their profiles pages like this

```
Service 1, Service 2, Service 3, Service 4, Service 5
```

However if the user chooses less than 5 services for example just 2 it results in this

```
Service 1, Service 2, , ,
```

Here is what I included in my view file

```
<p><%= @user.profile.services_1 %>, <%= @user.profile.services_2 %>, <%= @user.profile.services_3 %>, <%= @user.profile.services_4 %>, <%= @user.profile.services_5 %></p>
```

How should I correct it to remove the surplus commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to collect the selected services into an array, then combine join them.

```
# in the controller
@services = []
@services << @user.profile.services_1 if @user.profile.services_1
@services << @user.profile.services_2 if @user.profile.services_2
@services << @user.profile.services_3 if @user.profile.services_3
@services << @user.profile.services_4 if @user.profile.services_4
@services << @user.profile.services_5 if @user.profile.services_5

# in the view
<p><%= @services.join(', ') %></p>
```

It might also be better to place this login in the model if you can't simplify it beyond this.

```
# in the model
def selected_services
  services = []
  services << services_1 if services_1.present?
  services << services_2 if services_2.present?
  services << services_3 if services_3.present?
  services << services_4 if services_4.present?
  services << services_5 if services_5.present?
  services
end

# in the controller
@services = @user.profile.selected_services
```

Comment: Many thanks HarlemSquirrel! Your 2nd suggestion of placing in in the model was spot on.

Comment: You're welcome! If that worked for you, you can up vote my answer.

Comment: I have done but I got a flash message saying it won't affect the public score because I have a reputation below 15.

Comment: Oh I see, no worries, you'll get there!